# XPathNodeIterator Current Value only for Parent

Tags: c#, xml, xpathnavigator, xpathnodeiterator

I am new to XPath.

Using C# I am trying to read  the XML file which has a parent node and multiple child nodes

With XPathNavigator, I do a Select on root/parent and assign this value to XPathNodeIterator
 `XPathNodeIterator ni = _xpathNavigator.Select(theTag);`

Then I move to Next
When I use
ni.Current.Value

I get text value from Parent as well as both Child1 and Child2

What I want to get is the value of Parent only

The OuterText is giving similar results.

Anybody aware of how to get this working?

Comment: it will be easier to understand your problem if you provide one sample xml that you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some xml such as:

```
<root>
  <outer>
    outerValue
    <inner1>innerValue1</inner1>
    <inner2>innerValue2</inner2>
  </outer>
</root>
```

and you're seeing "outerValueinnerValue1innerValue2" as the returned value of /outer.

I don't believe there is any property on the object that will give you outerValue alone. Obviously you could iterate through the child nodes and remove their values from the concat'd string but thats horrible.

Probably best to add a new child node to your xml eg.

```
<root>
  <outer>
    <value>outerValue</value>
    <inner1>innerValue1</inner1>
    <inner2>innerValue2</inner2>
  </outer>
</root>
```